# Does Stunning duration stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, monsters

Last session the party was confronted by a hammerclaw which has a rather devastating sonic attack which can stun for 1d4 rounds and deals 4d6 dmg. My question is this:

If the hammerclaw stuns someone dealing X damage and stunning them for X rounds, and then uses the sonic blast on them a second time the round after do they:

A. Have to make a second save and stack the additional stunning duration with the duration of the first stun

B. Have to make a second save but the duration becomes only the longest of the two independently rolled durations

c. Make a second save and if failed, take the damage but ignore any additional stunning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they do not stack, they overlap.

> ### Stacking Effects
>
> Spells that provide bonuses or penalties on attack rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and other attributes **usually do not stack with themselves**. More generally, two bonuses of the same type don’t stack even if they come from different spells (or from effects other than spells; see Bonus Types, above).

<sup>([Combining Magical Effects](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#combiningMagicalEffects))</sup>

So these stuns would only stack if they explicitly included a rule saying they do. The default is that they don’t.

Instead,

> #### One Effect Makes Another Irrelevant
>
> Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. Both spells are still active, but one has rendered the other useless in some fashion.

<sup>([Combining Magical Effects](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#combiningMagicalEffects))</sup>

In this case, one or the other stun is irrelevant because the other has the longer duration. You cannot be “double-stunned,” so the one with the shorter duration has no significance.

However, if an effect should dispel, say, one effect from the target, and removes the longer-duration stun, the second, shorter-duration stun effect would remain and the target would still be stunned (but for somewhat less time).

For example, say the hammerclaw attacks Alice and stuns her for 2 rounds. In the next round (1 round remaining on that stun), it attacks her again, and stuns her for 4 rounds. She is now subject to two stun effects: one with a 1-round duration remaining, and another with a 4-round duration remaining. Since stun is an all-or-none condition, she is just stunned, not extra stunned or anything, and will remain so as long as at least one of these effects remains on her.

However, her friend Bob casts an area *dispel magic* and dispels the 4-round stun.<sup>1</sup> Now she only has the stun with 1 round remaining on her. She will only be stunned for 1 round more, instead of 4.

1. <sub>I am assuming that this is a magical effect that can be dispelled, which may not be true. Just pretend it is for the purposes of this example. Note that if we get *hyper-technical*, the rules for stacking effects refer explicitly to *spells*. The general consensus is to use these rules pretty broadly for most effects, not just spells, but as-written there aren’t really any good rules for stacking non-spell effects (which is why most people just use the spell rules).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### The durations do not stack, but overlap

When a creature is subject to multiple effects with a duration, the general rule, found on PHB p171-172*, is that all of them apply as normal. Numerical modifiers can stack (if they come from different sources), but otherwise they do exactly as they say.

The first application gives the target the Stunned condition for the duration. The second also gives the target the Stunned condition for the duration. While either application lasts, the target is Stunned, and ending one does not neccesarily end the other (this is mostly relevant for dispelled spells).

The target can only have the Stunned condition once - it's either stunned or not - so while either lasts, the target cannot take actions, takes a -2 to AC and loses his Dex bonus to AC.

(This will effectively be the same as option B, except if someone has an ability that removes one, but not all, effects that stun a creature).

---

*= *Stacking effects*. Unfortunately, this is only explicitly spelled out for magical effects. There is no explicit rule support for re-applying extraordinary abilities.

However, while it is hard to prove a negative, the rules never mention re-applied effects stacking in duration, and the only place where re-applied effects *are* mentioned clearly state they overlap as above, not stack. Additionally, there is no conflict in the rules when effects simply apply seperately exactly as stated, lasting for their normal listed duration.

Comment: Answer would be improved with a rule citation that addresses the points you make in terms of overlapping effects/conditions.

Comment: Annoyingly, I could only find an explicit quote when it comes to magical effects (and the question does not specify if the attack is magical in nature). I wrote my rationale why the same would hold for extraordinary abilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it updates, but not stacks
Example:

Round 1: sonic attack - people take damage and are stunned

Round 2: sonic attack

1. Have each person make a save

   a. Apply relevant damage
2. If a player fails to resist the stun

   a. Compare the stun duration with their current stun duration. If the new stun duration is longer, apply that duration

   b If the player was stunned for 2 rounds, and new duration is 4 rounds, the player is now stunned for 4 rounds.

   c. If player was stunned for 3 rounds, and the new duration is 1 round, then nothing changes

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get a chance. Can you point to any rules text supporting your interpretation?

Comment: While your answer is clear and concise, its generally considered bad form on this site to give an answer that does not reference the rules at all in response to a question about the rules, such as this one.  The best answers reference what's actually said in the rules, and how that applies here(or states there's no rules when that's the case), and then appends any personal rulings afterwards, while explaining why there's a need for the ruling(are the normal rules insufficient or do they play poorly?).